# got KeyError 1, have no idea what is wrong

Tags: python, if-statement, input, types, keyerror

I wrote a simple function to exercise set methodes. can somebody tell me why I got this error and how to solve it? thank you very much

```
n = int(input())
s = set(map(int, input().split()))
N=int(input())
for i in range(N):
    inputlist=input()
    if len(inputlist)==3:
        s.pop()
    else: 
        newl=inputlist.split()
        comand=newl[0]
        val=int(newl[1])
        
        if comand=='remove':
            s.remove(val)
        else:
            s.discard(val)
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
    "my input:"
    3
    1 2 3
    2
    pop
    remove 1
```

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-6ab5ebb8e508> in <module>
     11         val=int(newl[1])
     12         if comand=='remove':
---> 13             s.remove(val)
     14         else:
     15             s.discard(val)

KeyError: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got an error because `element{1}` `pop` before, you can use `try...except` to not get error if `element don't exist`.

try this:

```
n = int(input())
s = set(map(int, input().split()))
N=int(input())
for i in range(N):
    inputlist=input()
    if len(inputlist)==3:
        s.pop()
    else: 
        newl=inputlist.split()
        comand=newl[0]
        val=int(newl[1])        
        if comand=='remove':
            try:
                s.remove(val)
            except:
                print('val not exist')
        else:
            s.discard(val)
```

Comment: @ZhengxiJiang, do you search for only solve this problem Or solve problem for always ::) another answer only solve this little problem :)))

Answer (score 0):

When you use `pop` in set, it pops first element of that set

In your case, you are popping first element first, which is 1, and trying to remove it in next step. Which raise you an error because that element can't be found

Comment: yes yes that is the reason, I found it out also, thanks man!